# Computing in Matlab, for a $n\times2$ matrix, for each row$\theta_{0}*\text{first element in row}+\theta_{1}*\text{second element in row}$

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix $A$ s.t each row is of length $2$ and with the first
element $=1$ for example 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\\
1 & 5\\
1 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I have a function $h(x)=\theta_{0}+\theta_{1}x$ . I defined 
$$
\theta=\begin{pmatrix}\theta_{0}\\
\theta_{1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and I would like to have a vector
$$
v=\begin{pmatrix}h(2)\\
h(5)\\
h(4)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I noted that if the rows are $r_{1},r_{2},r_{3}$ (for example $r_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2\end{pmatrix}$)
then: 
$$
v=\begin{pmatrix}r_{1}*\theta\\
r_{2}*\theta\\
r_{3}*\theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$

How can I use what I noted to compute $v$ ?

Currently, I Isolate the second column of $A$ and I apply the function
on that vector, but I feel that by using the all $1$ column of $A$
we can calculate $v$ with the rows of $A$.

Note: The setting is a machine learning class, the all $1$ column
was added for this reason, but I don't see how I can code this

Comment: This is just a matrix times vector product. For example, $v = A \cdot \theta$.

Comment: @HansEngler - thanks! I can't believe I didn't see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the matrix - vector product $A \cdot \theta$.